# Алгоритм на Java

Tags: java

Есть классы, которые представляют из себя объекты, их - огромное количество (например класс.... Carrot). В каждом их этих классов есть переменная data, которая является строкой.
В другом, главном классе, я читаю из файла строки. И нужно проверять: если строка из файла совпадает со строкой в одном из других классов,то нужно вызывать конструктор этого класса (т.е. сделать его экземпляр).

Вот начал делать, но запнулся. Не знаю как.

```
public static String[] objectList = {Carrot.getData(),
                                 Cactus.getData()
                                };

            for(int im = 0; im < objectList.length; im++)
        {
            if(objectList[im].equals(jo.get("data").toString()))
            {
                // вот тут нужно создавать экземпляр класса, с которым совпадает строка
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(objectList[im].equals(jo.get("data").toString())) {
     MyClass myObject=jo.clone();
 }
```

При этом надо озаботиться тем чтобы в ваших классах был реализован метод `clone()` типа:

```
public class Carrot {
    @Override
    public Carrot clone() {
        //blah-blah
    }
}
```

Тогда `clone()` вернет правильный объект, в противном случае получите просто `Object`

Answer (score 0):

набросал шаблон кода:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Input:
        // вот массив ваших обьектов которые содержат в себе строку
        Object[] items = null;

        // 1. сначала создадим маппинг строк к обьектам
        // (это упрощает нам задачу в будущем
        Map<String, Class<?>> mappings = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>(items.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            mappings.put(getString(items[i]), items[i].getClass());
        }

        // Input:
        // массив строк которые вы получаете из файла
        String[] fromFile = null;

        // 2. ищем совпадения
        for (int i = 0; i < fromFile.length; i++) {

            // получаем тип по строке
            Class<?> type = mappings.get(fromFile);

            // пропускаем те для которых нет совпадения
            if (null == type) {
                continue;
            }

            // создаем новый экземпляр
            try {
                Object newInstance = createInstance(type);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // обрабатываем ошибку
            }
        }

    }

    // Input:
    // метод который получает строку из обьекта
    private static String getString(Object item) {
        return "abc";
    }

    // Input:
    // метод который создает новые экземпляры обьектов
    private static Object createInstance(Class<?> type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return type.newInstance();
    }

}
```

там где требуется изменить код есть соответствующая пометка `// Input:`, т.е вам надо:
1) проинициализировать список обьектов (в том числе поменять тип на Carrot)
2) добавить логику считывания строк из файла (если же вы планируете делать поиск по ходу считывания, то придется еще поменять сам цикл)
3) поменять метод который получает строку из обьекта (в моем случае это просто заглушка в вашем это может быть использование геттера getData, etc...)
4) поменять создание обьектов - в приведеном примере мы создаем обьект по его типу с использованием конструктора без параметров но у ваших типов такого конструктора может и не быть, посему есть2  варианта: а) поменять метод таким образом чтоб он правильно конструировал обьекты б) использовать клонирование и переложить эти обязаности непосредственно на конкретный тип, см ответ [@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) ♦